# Is the DCEF3 being kept up to date?

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded, tchromium

When I go to **chrome://version/** in my chromium wrapper component ([DCEF3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3)) I get this:

[image: chromium version]

**My question is:** Are these versions up to date or [dcef3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) project is not active?

I want to start a windows project with Chromium, I prefer Delphi for this but [CefSharp](http://cefsharp.github.io/) seems a more active project. I'm wonder if it would be more advantageous to use it instead [DCEF3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3).

Comment: there is an issue open on github asking a similar question: https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3/issues/15 but it has no answer yet

Comment: Anyone can help, please?

Comment: There is CEF4Delphi https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi of which I think worth to try,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this project seems to be dead. I could contact the owner by email sometime ago, i even offered to donate to help, but at the time he did not have a paypal account.

It's sad because it's a very good and stable component, but if no updates are made, at least using new Chromium versions, it will become obsolete soon.

Comment: It's a pity but thank you. Are you looking for alternatives?

Comment: Currently i'm still using DCEF3 and studying its source ; i could not find other alternatives so maybe i'll need to update the source myself.